# Detect ASP.NET Session Timeout - ASP.NET_SessionId method not working

Tags: asp.net, session, session-cookies

I'm trying to detect Asp.NET Session Timeout to redirect user to a timeout page; i've checked various methods, most of them similar to

http://aspalliance.com/520_Detecting_ASPNET_Session_Timeouts.2

(if `Session.IsNewSession` and `ASP.NET_SessionId cookie` exists, then is a timeout)

The problem is that the "ASP.NET_SessionId" cookie is always present for me, even if i just started debugging, thus giving me always a false timeout flag when starting the web site for the first time.

UPDATE:
For testing, i've just created an Empty Asp.NET Web Application with following codes:

**BasePage.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace TestApp.classes
{
    public class BasePage : Page
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            if (Context.Session != null)
            {
                if (Session.IsNewSession)
                {
                    string szCookieHeader = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                    if ((null != szCookieHeader) && (szCookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("sessionTimeout.htm");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Global.asax**

```
using System;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var a = "";
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var b = "";
        }

        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
using System;
using TestApp.classes;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : BasePage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      <sessionState timeout="1"></sessionState>
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Then Hit F5, and i will be redirected to `sessionTimeout.htm`. Why?

Comment: if cookie is always present, why do you check it? necessary to check `Session.IsNewSession` only or remove the cookie

Comment: because in theory ASP.NET_SessionId cookie would not be present at first visit.

Comment: you have to use the Cookie.Discard Property and you can change in web.config for cookie state false.

Comment: Thank you, can you please explain in more detail this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use cookie when you develop your website. There are other ways to store data, e.g. you can store the data specific to a user in database

Note that `"Cookieless = false"` attrubute of `SessionState` element in `web.config` which means the sessionID of the current session will be saved in the client machine as a cookie

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

Default settings for `ASP.NET` session state are defined in the `machine.config` file and can be overridden in the `web.config` file in the application's root folder. By ensuring that the above line appears in the root `web.config` file, you enable cookieless sessions

Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

So check only for `Session.IsNewSession` and disable cookie

Comment: In all methods i've seen no one suggest to use cookieless mode (and i need cookies); maybe there is something other wrong on my configuration?